# Rails : select ActiveSupport::Callbacks on options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, activesupport

I have a controller in which I have to access the list of my callbacks.

I use this to filter them :

```
_process_action_callbacks.select{|f| f.kind != :around}
```

I'm trying to filter them also on the options (i.e. on the 'if' and 'unless' arrays).

I tried this

```
_process_action_callbacks.select{|f| f.if.any? }
```

but there is apparently no 'if' method.

I was baffled as I have this :

```
_process_action_callbacks.select{
  |f| f.kind != :around
}.first
=> #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fd1a16295d8
 @chain_config=
  {:scope=>[:kind],
   :terminator=>
    #<Proc:0x007fd1928375c8@/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12 (lambda)>,
   :skip_after_callbacks_if_terminated=>true},
 @filter=:foo,
 @if=["action_name == 'create'"],        # 'if' seems present
 ...
```

and also this :

```
_process_action_callbacks.select{|f| f.kind != :around}.first.instance_variables
=> [:@chain_config, :@name, :@kind, :@filter, :@key, :@if, :@unless]
```

Is there a way to get the options or the 'if' of the Callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is no `accessor` or `reader` method for `@if`, checked [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb). But you can still get it using [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) method.

```
_process_action_callbacks.select do |f|
  f.instance_variable_get(:@if).any?
end
```